# CSS extend a inner element border horizontal though the whole parent row

Tags: javascript, css

I am dynamically generating a table. The row has many cells. One cell has a `ul` list in it. Some other cells in the same row have the same kind of `ul` list with the exact same number of `li` element.

So I want to strike a feeling that the `li` items, though they are in different cells, they are visually on the same row. Without a border, it's hard to match them in the same row. So I want to add a border line in the `ul/li` but since it is in the cell, I can't make it wide across the whole table row to connect with the other list in another cell in the same row...

Changing html is troublesome. Any CSS way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you provide a visual please? Or full code example would be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re-reading your post, you're just trying to put an underline after the `li` rows? If so, you can use the same approach as my answer below, just don't use `transform` to move it back up so that the border is after the text

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
td {
  padding: 1em;
}
li:not(:last-child):after {
  content: '\00a0';
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>foo</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>foo</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>foo</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can use an absolutely positioned pseudo element on the `li` draw the line, and make the `table` relatively positioned so that the line expands the width of the table.

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
.strike:after {
  content: '\00a0';
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>foo</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li class="strike">foo</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li>foo</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>bar</li>
        <li class="strike">foo</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Assuming this is what the OP is asking for (hard to tell from the question, exactly) - this is a nice solution!

Comment: I am testing this code now. but I found that my question missed one important point which is that there are empty cells in between the cells containing the list. So the cells with the list in them are not consecutive in the row.

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to say without seeing some code... But if I understand correctly, there is no easy way to put one line across table cells the way you are describing.  You could however apply a bottom border to the `li` elements in each row like this (adds border to the third list item in each list):

```
td li:nth-child(3) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6cxj3e5y/)

Its not exactly what youre looking for but it helps identify items in a row.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your problem I came to the following conclusion and result, you are facing problem reading cells in row.
You can achieve this by:

```
ul {  
border: 1px solid black;  
}  
row {  
border: 1px solid black;  
}
```